# Sum of Square Prime Reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Does anyone know what value the sum of squares of inverse of primes is equal to in terms of other known mathematical function? That is:

$$
\sum_{p\in \mathbb{P}} \frac{1}{p^2}
$$

where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes. This sum definitely converges by comparison to $1/n^2$ but I was wondering if it was an important constant and/or the value of a specific notable function.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared

Comment: @tired Right, typo. Thank you for the link (y)

Answer (score 8):

Such series is close to $\log\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$, since $\frac{1}{p^2}$ is close to $\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+\frac{1}{p^2}}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}=\text{arctanh}\frac{1}{p^2}$ and by Euler's product

$$ \sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \log\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)},\qquad \sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)=\log\zeta(2)$$
hence
$$\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p^2}\approx \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)} = \log\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}.$$
I leave to you to refine such (already quite accurate) approximation through a similar idea.

Comment: Wonderful approximation! (+1).